# How to add indentation to all verbatim environment?

Tags: indentation, verbatim

I have a style where all paragraphs have indentation of about 5cm. Verbatim environment does not have any indentation to the combination of paragraphs and verbatim environments does not look good. Something like this:

> ```
>              This is paragraph ...
>           Next line of the same paragraph.
> ```
>
> and this is verbatim

Is it possible to define an global indent for verbatim environment?

Comment: Why don't  you use `listings.sty`?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? I don't think I understand what is going on exactly. Is the verbatim in the margin?

Answer (score 5):

Some extented packages provide this feature. For example, `fancyvrb`:

```
% in preamble \usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin=2em]
hello
\end{Verbatim}
```

Global setting can be done by `\fvset`:

```
\fvset{xleftmargin=2em}
```

Answer (score -1):

what about this idea:
You can but all you verbatim environment inside quote environments.
If that will fit your needs, you can of course define

```
\newenvironment{qverb}{\begin{quote}\begin{verbatim}}{\end{verbatim}\end{quote}}
```

your own "qverb" environment for that case.

Greets

Comment: It cannot (in fact, impossible) work. You can't use `verbatim` env in another environment's argument.

Comment: @Leo-Liu - I'm sorry to tell your comment is wrong. I just tried

`\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{verbatim}
Hallo 
\end{verbatim}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}\begin{verbatim}
Hallo 
\end{verbatim}\end{quote}
\blindtext
\end{document}`


and it worked well. I think you ment one cannot use other environments INSIDE of `verbatim`, did you?

Comment: I don't want to argue. You can use `verbatim` env in `quote` env, but you cannot use `verbatim` in **arguments** of `\newenvironment` and use it without errors. Just put your definition of `qverb` in your document and have a try.

Comment: And you can refer this FAQ: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Comment: @Leo-Liu: Okay, I got it - you are right. Thanks for teaching me!